# NodeJS how use connect obj in different file

Tags: node.js, express, transactions

i think this is mainly a design-pattern challange.
At the start of my Program i want to connect to my MongoDB Database and I'll get the connection object back.

```js
//app.js
const start = async () => {
  try {
    const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

start();
```

`registerCustomer` is a function that gets executed if a specific post request is send.
Inside `registerCustomer` I want to use the `db` object that gets runtime defined in the `app.js` file. I want to write something like in the following code example but this will of course **not work**, because I have no access to the `db` object.

```js
const registerCustomer = async (req, res) => {
    const session = await db.startSession(); //this will fail because I have no reference to the db object.
try {
    session.startTransaction();

    await Customer.create([{ firstName: "john" }], { session: session });
    await Customer.create([{ firstName: "Doe" }], { session: session });
    await session.commitTransaction();
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
  }
  finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
```

How can I solve this problem the most elegant way? How can I access the `db` object from other functions?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Directory Structure

```
app.js
|__database
    |__conn.js
```

**This is your MongoDB connection file `fileName: conn.js`**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const DB = process.env.DATABASE;
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Connection Successful on 'mongoosecrud' Cluster");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Connection NOT Successful" + err);
  });
```

**Now simply you can require this connection file in your root `server.js` or `app.js` file**

```
require("./database/conn.js")
```

Comment: Hey Smit, thanks for the answer but this solves not my problem. I have to use the `db` object in other files.